# Block for async fetch to complete in webpacked application

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

The issue I'm trying to solve is to block on the fetching on an external json file, so a configuration object can be consumed elsewhere. Essentially, there are three files contributing to this:

`builder.jsx` 
`runtime.jsx`

and a json file:

`config.settings.json`

The `runtime.jsx` needs to load the `config.settings.json` from a uri and return the resolved object data to `builder.jsx` where it's parsed into a configuration object which is exported for consumption all over the code.

The problem I'm having is that the object exported from `runtime.jsx` is only resolved to a result after it has been read by `builder.jsx`, so consequently an `undefined` object is inputted if the Promise has not resolved and the code in `builder.jsx` fails.

What further complicates the situation is that `builder.jsx` exports an object that is used to initialize many other components throughout the application.

Refactoring the logic to populate `builder.jsx`'s configuration object via a Promise.then() doesn't help since the exported object is undefined until the Promise resolves, so all the components that initialize with it consequently fail if the Promise hasn't resolved.

It's not possible to update the components elsewhere in the code since they're effectively blackboxed, so what I'm trying to figure out how to do is make the code wait until the critical json configuration has been loaded, before it continues.

My question is; is there a way to load an external dependency and explicitly block the code from continuing until it's loaded?

**runtime.jsx**

```
let exportedResult;

fetch(require('/path/to/config.settings.json'))
.then(result => exportedResult = result.json());

export default exportedResult;
```

**builder.jsx**

```
import config from './runtime.jsx';

const globalSettings = {
   taskParameter: config.taskParams,
   someHardcodeValue: "avalue"

};

export default globalSettings;
```

**config.settings.json**

```
{
   "taskParams": "random"
}
```

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to wait for the promise.

Comment: How does that work in the context of existing code? As far as I can see that would mean all dependent code would need to be nested inside the `then` clause since it can't be called until the parent Promise has resolved. A simple need to configure any async event would potentially necessitate a massive rewrite - all because there's no way to `Wait()`.

Comment: Yes; you can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control runtime.jsx, have it export a promise-returning function, not just the promise...

**runtime.jsx**

```
function getConfig {
    return fetch(require('/path/to/config.settings.json')).then(result => result.json());
}

export default getConfig;
```

The builder code continues this pattern...

**builder.jsx**

```
import config from './runtime.jsx';

const globalSettings = {
   someHardcodeValue: "avalue"
};

function initializeGlobalSettings () {
   config.getConfig().then(result => {
       globalSettings.taskParameter = result.taskParams;
   });
}

export default initializeGlobalSettings;
```

And the user of builder.jsx imports it, triggers `initializeGlobalSettings()` whenever it sees fit, and initiates whatever relies on that result in the returned promise's `then()`.

Comment: I ended up using this as the basis for a bit of rework. Thanks alot.